# Ubuntu 20.04 - "Unhandled error message: The name 1.1001 was not provided by any .service file" when trying to mount Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro via USB

Tags: 20.04, usb, mount, nautilus

When I try to mount my Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro on my Ubuntu 20.04 via USB, I get "Unhandled error message: The name :1.1001 was not provided by any .service files" from Nautilus. It fails to mount. I have a Lenovo Y510p.

Tried every USB port.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Similar issue I have managed to solve with '`nautilus -q`' typed in terminal. Worth a try. Don't need to restart the computer.

Comment: The nautilus seemed to interfere, -q quits nautilus. Then try to connect and works.

Comment: I had the similar error message ("Unhandled error message: the name 1.104 was not provided by any .service files") when connecting iPhone 5 to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. `nautilus -q` helped.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to `nautilus -q`, I also had to run this to work:

```
sudo killall gvfsd
nautilus -q
```

No need to reboot anything. Just plug again and open Nautilus.

Comment: Restarting my comp didn't work, `nautilus -q` alone didn't work.  I needed to `sudo killall gvfsd` as well.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem on my Redmi 5 Plus.
I am on Ubuntu 20.04.

```
Unhandled error message: The name:1.177 was not provided by any .service files
```

I tried connecting my phone via USB on same port as usual, except it had just been used by a USB printer (EPSON ET-2756) on the same port without restarting the PC between the two connections. Tried on all other USB ports: same message.

I solved it like this:

- Restart Redmi without connecting it to a computer.
- Restart computer without any USB port connected especially devices such as printers or scanners.
- Connect your Redmi via usual USB port, when prompted with **Use USB to...** select **Transfer files**.
- Now open your Redmi phone's location on Ubuntu. No error message should appear

[image: Proof of USB connection to Redmi phone after restart of Ubuntu 20.4]

Comment: I confirm  that restarting the computer works indeed. Is there a way to "reset" the USB port from command line without having to restart the computer?

Comment: Happens on Mint too, only it successfully mounts but the error appears when trying to copy files.

Comment: Also the nautilus -q.

Comment: I use Nemo on Mint so it doesn't seem to be manager specific, and resetting lightdm sometimes solves it. It worked for a HTCphone but not for a Nikon cam.